# Writing Per-Handler Middleware

Tags: http, go, middleware

I'm looking to pull some repetitive logic out of my handlers and put it into some per-handler middleware: specifically things like CSRF checks, checking for an existing session value (i.e. for auth, or for preview pages), etc.

I've read [a few articles on this](http://justinas.org/writing-http-middleware-in-go/), but many examples focus on a per-server middleware (wrapping `http.Handler`): I have a smaller set of handlers that need the middleware. Most of my other pages do not, and therefore if I can avoid checking sessions/etc. for those requests the better.

My middleware, so far, typically looks something like this:

```
func checkCSRF(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // get the session, check/validate/create the token based on HTTP method, etc.
        // return HTTP 403 on a failed check
        // else invoke the wrapped handler h(w, r)
    }
}
```

However, in many cases I want to pass a variable to the wrapped handler: a generated CSRF token to pass to the template, or a struct that contains form data—one piece of middleware checks the session for the presence of some saved form data before the user hits a `/preview/` URL, else it redirects them away (since they have nothing to preview!).

I'd like to pass that struct along to the wrapped handler to save having to duplicate the session.Get/type assertion/error checking logic I just wrote in the middleware.

I could write something like:

```
type CSRFHandlerFunc func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, t string)
```

... and then write the middleware like so:

```
func csrfCheck(h CSRFHandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
     return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // get the session, check/validate/create the/a token based on HTTP method, etc.
        // return HTTP 403 on a failed check
        // else invoke the wrapped handler and pass the token h(w, r, token)
    }
```

... but that raises a few questions:

- Is this a sensible way to implement per-handler middleware and pass per-request variables?
- Prior to testing this (don't have access to my dev machine!), if I need to wrap a handler with multiple pieces of middleware, I assume I can just `r.HandleFunc("/path/preview/", checkCSRF(checkExisting(previewHandler)))`? The issue I'm seeing here is that the middleware is now tightly coupled: the wrapped middleware now needs to receive and then pass on the variable from the outer middleware. This makes extending http.HandlerFunc trickier/more convoluted.
- Would **[gorilla/context](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context)** fit better here and allow me to avoid writing 2-3 custom handler types (or a generic handler type) — and if so, how would I make use of it? Or could I implement my own "context" map (and run into issues with concurrent access?).

Where possible I'm trying to avoid falling for the "don't get caught writing a library" trap, but middleware is something that I'm likely to add/build on later in the project's life, and I'd like to "get it right" the first time around.

Some guidance on this would be much appreciated. Go's been *great* so far for writing a web application, but there's not a ton of examples around at this stage in its life and I'm therefore leaning on SO a little.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for a convenient way to pass additional parameters to your middleware, right?

Now, it's important to define what those parameters are. They could be some configuration values for your middleware – those can be set when the Handler type is being constructed). Instead of `NewMyMiddleware(MyHandler)`, you do `NewMyMiddleware(MyHandler, "parameter")`, no problem here.

But in your case it seems like you want to pass per-request parameters, like a CSRF token. Passing those into the handler function would modify its signature and it would deviate from the standard `Handler[Func]` interface. You're right about middleware being more tightly coupled in this case.

You kind of mentioned the solution yourself – a context map **is**, in my opinion, a viable tool for this.  It's not **that** hard to write one yourself – you basically need a `map[*http.Request]interface{}` and an `RWMutex` for safe concurrent access. Still, simply using `gorilla/context` should suffice – it seems like a (relatively) mature, well-written package with a nice API.

Shameless plug: if you're dealing with CSRF checks, why not try out my [nosurf](https://github.com/justinas/nosurf) package?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. gorilla/context seems to be the way to go here then—although I'm a little confused by the way the docs show setting keys/key types? RE: nosurf – it's probably a bit heavy for my needs. I'm using server-side sessions and would prefer to keep my tokens there; I also would have to exempt the majority of my routes as I only have a couple of forms. Otherwise it looks like a solid library!

Comment: Not sure how `gorilla/context` confuses you. Though that might be out of scope for this question. Hit me up directly? As for nosurf: you should actually be able to plug it in by wrapping only specific route handlers (`mux.HandleFunc("/hello", nosurf.New(myHandler))`). I haven't really tested this case, but it should work in theory.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, although as it returns a `http.Handler` (and not `http.HandleFunc`) it's unlikely to work (from looking at the API docs). I'll also flick you a quick email re: gorilla/context.